# Combine multiple JPEGs into one

Tags: imagemagick

I have folder of JPEG files named 0_0, 0_1, 1_0, 1_1, etc. First number is column and second one is row. I want to combine them into one JPEG file. How would I go about doing this? I have looked into ImageMagick but I don't know what parameters to use and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is

```
montage.exe -mode concatenate -tile 1x14 [0-9]*_[0-9]*.jpg miff:- | convert.exe - +append final.jpg
```

Note: If you have pictures with double-digit number (4_15, 10_1), You must add a zero to the files with numbers from 0-9 (04_15, 10_01)

This RegEx will take care of that (Bulk Rename Utility)

```
Search: (\d{1})_(\d{1}).jpg 
Replace: 0\1_0\2
```

Answer (score 2):

Relevant ImageMagick documentation is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/).

Try:

```
montage -geometry +0+0 0_0.jpg 0_1.jpg 1_0.jpg 1_1.jpg output.jpg
```

Comment: Since I have images from 0_0 to 9_13, it wouldn't be efficient to write out everything. In the mean time I've figured it out `montage.exe -mode concatenate -tile 1x14 [0-9]*_[0-9]*.jpg miff:- | convert.exe - +append final.jpg` and renaming all `X_0-X_9` to `X_00-X_09` with this RegEx Search: `(\d{1})_(\d{1}).jpg` and replace: `\1_0\2`

Comment: @AntonioKovačević, that sounds like a good solution. You should create it as an answer and then mark it as accepted.